# Value retrieved from a float is 0.0 ?

Tags: java, floating-point

This function returns a 0.0 althought all the values are float and are retrieved correctly from the shared preferences ! what could be the error?

```
float BMR(){

    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String  Weight =customSharedPreference.getString("weightpref", null);
    float weight = Float.valueOf(Weight);

    String  Height = customSharedPreference.getString("heightpref",null);
    float height = Float.valueOf(Height);
    String Age = customSharedPreference.getString("agepref", null);
    float age = Float.valueOf(Age);

    int gender = customSharedPreference.getInt("genderpref", 0);

    Toast.makeText(StatsActivity.this, Age, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if ( gender == 0){
        bmr = (float) (10.0 *weight + 6.25 * height - 5.0 * age + 5.0);
    }
    if(gender == 1){
        bmr = (float) (10.0 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5.0 * age- 161.0);
    }

    String bmrtest = String.valueOf(bmr);
    Toast.makeText(StatsActivity.this, "bmr is "+bmrtest, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return bmr;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? This function does not actually declare a variable named `bmr` anywhere.

Comment: You need to debug your code and provide values of gender, weight, height, age at the line of calculation of bmr.

Comment: I am using a toast to see the content of the shared prefs, and I get the correct values stored in the sharedprefs.

Comment: Also, it would probably be better (judging from what little I can see of your code) to make gender an enum with male and female as fields in it.

Comment: I would use `double` instead of `float` It will simplify your code and have less representation error. I would also use parseDouble instead of valueOf as the later creates an object you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if gender is not 0 or 1? Your bmr would remain unassigned (to 0.0).

If that's the problem, you may consider, for the future, to:

- put an else clause after your if's
- group those two ifs into an elseif (since they are exclusive)
- at the very least put in an assert to check that gender is indeed 1 or 0

Comment: I am using a toast to see the content of the shared prefs, and I get the correct values stored in the sharedprefs , including the gender !

Comment: So, I take it you have debugged step by step and you do go into one of the two if clauses, right? And are you sure that you have non-zeroes for all the values you have in your expression? There's not many more places this can go wrong...

Comment: Would i really need the debugger if I use the toast and it gives me the values that I want?